# Fragment Popbackstack calling Replace of my root fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am using `getSupportFragmentManager()` to populate the **fragment A** in my `MainActivity` and then I have button in Second and Third `Fragment`.

**MainActivity.java**

```
FrameLayout frame;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    frame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,new FirstFragment()).addToBackStack("first").commit();
}
```

And in `FirstFragment.java` same while click on Button I am navigating to **SecondFragment**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        Log.d("TAG","First Fragment OncreateView");
        clicButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.click);
        clicButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,new SecondFragment()).addToBackStack("second").commit();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Now what I am doing when I am clicking on button from **firstfragment** I am using "add" to add **SecondFragment** and on **secondFragment** I am using "replace" to going forward to **thirdFragment**.

Problem I'm facing is that when I'm coming back from **thirdFragment** it calls `onCreateView()` method  of **firstFragment** and it loads **SecondFragment**.java. So i don't want to call Fragment First screen `onCreateView()` method.

Answer (score 0):

In the MainActivity you use add() to add the first fragment and then in the first and second fragment you should use replace().

As I can see from your code, you create the first fragment in the MainActivity's onCreate(), so if you don't need to remove it later on back press to show your MainActivity, you shouldn't add it to back stack. So in this case the code for adding the first fragment would be

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,new FirstFragment()).commit();
```

In the first fragment you should use

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new SecondFragment()).addToBackStack("second").commit();
```

Andin the second

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new ThirdFragment()).addToBackStack("third").commit();
```

This way when the third fragment is showing, pressing the back button will show the second fragment and next press to the back button will show the first fragment. If you press back while the first fragment is showing, you will close your app.

**Edit:**

OK, you show your first then second fragment by calling add(). The problem is that when you call replace() instead of add() from second to third fragment, call to replace() is equivalent to calling remove() for both first and second fragment and then add() for the third one (because that is what replace() do - removes all previous fragments and then adds the new one). addToBackStack then records that transaction. So, when you pop that transaction from the back stack you add both the first and second fragment (second on top of the first, so the second one is visible) and onCreateView is consequently called for both fragments as well.

Comment: thanks Colens, actually my requirement is intended where i need to put second fragment by using "add" and third fragment by using "replace" if i use in Main activity "add" also for populating first fragment also then while coming back from third fragment its calling oncreateView of first fragment